# Tkinter, cursor en entry al abrir la aplicacion

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

soy nuevo en python.

Quisiera que al abrir mi apicacion el cursor para escribir ya este posicionado dentro de un Entry.
Asimismo, que al abrir un Toplevel, un boton ya este seleccionado para unicamente dar enter y ejecutar su command.

Por ejemplo, que al abrir esta ventana el cursor se posicione para escribir en serialEntry:

```
window=tk.Tk()
window.title("FT Files")
window.geometry("500x300")
texto=tk.Label(window,text="Introduce un numero de serie:", font=16)
texto.pack()
serialEntry=tk.Entry(window, font=16)
serialEntry.pack()
```

Y que al abrir esta ventana, quitButton este seleccionado para dar enter y ejecutar su command:

```
def passFunc(path):
    shutil.copy(path, "Z:/#-public/aPruebas/Softel/Empaque/")
    exito_window=tk.Toplevel()
    text=tk.Label(exito_window, text="¡El registro fue recuperado con exito!", font=16)
    text.pack()
    text.config(pady=10)
    quitButton=tk.Button(exito_window, text="Aceptar", font=12, command=exito_window.destroy)
    quitButton.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ambos casos debes usar el método `widget.focus` o `widget.focus_set()` para asignarle el foco al widget. `widget.focus_set()` es común a todos los widgets de TKinter, así como homólogo `widget.focus_get()`.

Por otro lado, asumo que darle el foco al botón es para habilitar que la ventana se cierre con solo pulsar <kbd>Enter</kbd>, en tal caso generalmente deberás enlazar el botón al evento `<Return>` de forma explícita.

Te dejo un ejemplo reproducible basando en tu ejemplo con ambas dudas agrupadas (al pulsar <kbd>Enter</kbd> en el `Entry` se abre la ventana secundaria)

```
import tkinter as tk

def pass_func(path):
    # shutil.copy(path, "Z:/#-public/aPruebas/Softel/Empaque/")
    exito_window = tk.Toplevel()
    text = tk.Label(
        exito_window, text="¡El registro fue recuperado con exito!", font=16
        )
    text.pack()
    text.config(pady=10)
    quit_button=tk.Button(exito_window, text="Aceptar", font=12, command=exito_window.destroy)
    quit_button.pack()
    quit_button.focus_set()
    quit_button.bind('<Return>', lambda _: exito_window.destroy())


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("FT Files")
window.geometry("500x300")
texto = tk.Label(window, text="Introduce un numero de serie:", font=16)
texto.pack()
serial_entry = tk.Entry(window, font=16)
serial_entry.pack()
serial_entry.focus_set()
serial_entry.bind('<Return>', lambda _: pass_func(""))

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Me sirvió muchisimo, gracias!